# How to dynamically load SAML settings.json based on custom property?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

I'm building a platform which needs to be able to support multiple SAML IdPs.

I'm using [python3-saml](https://github.com/onelogin/python3-saml).

Each IdP integration has it's own login page URL with some custom properties in the querystring to identify certain properties of that users visit.  This approach is necessary in my instance to configure the user based on their first visit.

When the user clicks "Login" I send a quest to my server at `[MYSERVERADDRESS]/sso2` which calls `auth.login(returnUrl)` and returns the MS Azure login address, I then forward the user to that URL, they log in and get forwarded to `[MYSERVERADDRESS]/acs` where I get the attributes.

The issue is that each of the IdPs has a different settings.json file.  I keep each of these settings.json files in a seperate folder named with the id for the IdP implementation in my system (not the same as the entityId).

On visiting `[MYSERVERADDRESS]/sso2` I can pick this id up by passing it in a json post or querystring params, but when the user is forwarded to `[MYSERVERADDRESS]/acs` I can't see any way to persist it and therefore I can't select the settings file based on that id.

**TLDR:** Is there any way to pass custom data (i.e. not the SAML response) to `[MYSERVERADDRESS]/acs` when the user is forwarded?

Worth noting that I don't have access to the IdP and so can't set up a custom property within the SAML response from there.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this using the `RelayState`.  In the samples provided in the [python3-saml](https://github.com/onelogin/python3-saml) documentation `RelayState` is a URL.  However, ultimately it's just a string.

So in calling `/sso2` I passed form data with a `RelayState` property in the same way as the SAML response passes a `RelayState` property when returning the user to `\acs`.

I was then able to pick up this `RelayState` property with `relayStateFormData = request.form['RelayState']` at the start of the saml endpoint on my server.

Then instead of putting the returnUrl in the `RelayState` property I put a serialised json object containing the properties I want to maintain state for and deserialised it server side.

I can now pass any number of properties through all stages of the saml negotiation.